# Identify section of static tableview programatically without using index

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a static tableview with some sections in my storyboard. I need to hide or show some of those sections depending on some conditions.

The order of those sections might vary in the future so I don't want to rely on its index to identify them in my code. I want my code to be as reusable and flexible as I can.

How can I achieve it? Is there something like tag or restorationID for sections?

EDIT: header title seems not to be a reliable option because the App will be localized.

Answer (score 0):

You can check your Section by its title, like this (in Swift, sorry!):

```
if tableView.headerViewForSection(indexPath.section)?.textLabel.text == "SomeSection"
{
    //This is some section
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm trying to workout a solution in objective-c like this:

`-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    NSLog(@"%@",[tableView headerViewForSection:section].textLabel.text);
    return [tableView headerViewForSection:section];
}`

but text is always null for some reason. Maybe I should use another delegate function to combine it with your answer.

Comment: Anyway I am realizing that the app will be localized so the title isn't a reliable option either. I should edit that in the main question though. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Add an enum of the different sections in the code and on the SB set the tag of the header to the enum value.

```
typedef enum : NSUInteger {
    MY_ENUM_A = 123,
    MY_ENUM_B = 321,
    MY_ENUM_C = 231,
} MY_ENUM;
```

And then

```
    UIView *header = [self.view viewWithTag:MY_ENUM_B];
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How can I set the header tag in a static tableview on the storyboard? I can't seem to find it.

Comment: click the cell in your storyboard (make sure you selected the cell using the navigator panel on the left) under the inspector on the right page there is a section called "View" which has mode, then tag.

Comment: how are you making / addidng the section headers ? in code ?

Comment: I add sections by storyboard. I just want to identify that sections without having to know the order. I have something like [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/oiqniv8dq0dcdsd/Screenshot%202015-03-29%2018.04.46.png?dl=0&raw=1)